# Scraping song lyrics with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Using Genius API, I acquire a song url to the lyrics page. I now want to webcrawl this using `beautifulsoup4`; however, I run into an error. Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def scrap_song_url(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    html = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    lyrics = html.find('div', class_='lyrics').get_text()

    return lyrics
```

Here, I am looking at the html for the lyrics page. For the sake of example, look at this specific url: `https://genius.com/Acceptance-permanent-lyrics`. Spelunking through the html, it appears that the lyrics are contained under `div` with class `'lyrics'` [image: HTML].

However, trying to find this using `html.find` returns a `NoneType` object and consequently `.get_text()` throws an error. I presume this means that, for some reason, the html tag (or whatever you call it, I don't really know html) is not being found. How can I acquire the lyrics from the div class `'lyrics'` from a given song lyrics url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Genius API Python wrapper that is supported and looks cool: [LyricsGenius](https://lyricsgenius.readthedocs.io/en/master/). You should try it. Installing is easy with pip: `pip install lyricsgenius`

From its documentation, collecting lyrics look much easier:

```py
from lyricsgenius import Genius

genius = Genius(token)
genius.search_artist('Andy Shauf')
artist.save_lyrics()
```

Comment: This is smarter than my solution! Always use other's people hard work when you can haha

Comment: Yeah, why would we reinvent the wheel? :)

Comment: help me guys, even when I pass the corrent token, it says "TypeError: InvalidToken" ??!!
pls help meeee

Answer (score 2):

Eh, I don't think that's where the lyrics are. With that specific page, I did:

```
lyrics = html.select("div[class*=Lyrics__Container]")
```

And got the lyrics (with a bunch of other HTMl mixed up there). There's a lot of cleaning to do. The '*' makes it you get all classes that *start* with Lyrics__Container because there are are a string of numbers and letters afterwards that I assume may change.

Answer (score 1):

You can pick out the individual lines by using [stripped_strings](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), after first isolating the verse/chorus sections with an [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector. There is some list unnesting in the outer part of the syntax.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from pprint import pprint

r = requests.get('https://genius.com/Acceptance-permanent-lyrics')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
pprint([i for j in [[line for line in verse.stripped_strings] for verse in soup.select('[data-scrolltrigger-pin]')] for i in j])

# pprint('\n'.join([i for j in [[line for line in verse.stripped_strings] for verse in soup.select('[data-scrolltrigger-pin]')] for i in j]))
```